# How do I know if a job submitted with SLURM is using gpus?

Tags: unix, gpu, cluster-computing, slurm

How do I know, after submitting a job in SLURM, if the job is using gpus?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it!

```
squeue -u username -o "%A %C %b"
```

gives me something like:

```
JOBID CPUS TRES_PER_NODE
41606201 6 gpu
41606309 4 N/A
```

**-o** (output)
**A** gives the jobID
**C** gives the number of CPUs

**b** gives gpu or N/A if not gpu

Comment: Are you sure? I'm not an expert, but I bet this tells you if your script requested GPUs, but not if it is really using them (as you seem to ask in your question).